# How can I list the second 50 customers in my Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin

My xamarin project works on the Android side of the listview. However, Ios does not work on the side. I receive and list my customer list from 1 to 50 on the web service. However, when the second 50 customers are listed, the scroll remains at the top of the list and remains in different positions. I've searched for a solution, but I haven't found it. Help, please.

```
    public partial class MusteriListesi : BasePage
{
    ListView listView;
    int bas;
    int bit;
    bool isLoading;
    public string mKodu = "";
    string mFirma = "";
    string mSehir = "";
    string mIlce = "";
    string mSemt = "";
    string mAdres = "";
    public string mCkp = "";
    public List<Musteriler> Items { get; set; }
    public MusteriListesi(string kodu, string firma, string sehir, string ilce, string semt, string adres,string ckp)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mKodu = kodu;mFirma = firma;mSehir = sehir;mIlce = ilce;mSemt = semt;mAdres = adres;mCkp = ckp;
        if (mCkp == "P")
        {
            this.Title = "Aday Listesi";
        }
        bas = 1;
        bit = 50;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mSehir))
        {
            mSehir = "Tüm Şehirler";
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mIlce))
        {
            mIlce = "Tüm İlçeler";
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mSemt))
        {
            mSemt = "Tüm Semtler";
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mKodu))
        {
            mKodu = "";
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mFirma))
        {
            mFirma = "";
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mAdres))
        {
            mAdres = "";
        }
        listView = MyListView;
        Items = new List<Musteriler>();
        Mobil.webService.KartServis service = new Mobil.webService.KartServis()
        {
            Url = Application.Current.Properties["servisyolu"].ToString()
        };
        List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler> MusteriLists = new List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler>(service.MusteriListele(mCkp, bas, bit, mKodu, mFirma, mSehir, mSemt, mIlce, mAdres, Application.Current.Properties["lisans"].ToString(), Application.Current.Properties["KNO"].ToString()));
        foreach (Mobil.webService.Musteriler items in MusteriLists)
        {
            Items.Add(new Musteriler { Kodu = items.Kodu, Firma = items.Firma, Adres = items.Adres, Telefon = items.Telefon, Sayi = items.Sayi });
        }
        listView.ItemsSource = Items;
    }
    async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (Musteriler)e.Item;
        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MusteriDetay(item.Kodu));
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
    protected void Handle_ItemAppearing(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        if(isLoading || Items.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (e.Item == Items[Items.Count - 1])
        {
            LoadItems();
        }
    }
    public async Task LoadItems()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        listView.ItemsSource = null;
        bas = bas + 50;
        bit = bit + 50;
        Mobil.webService.KartServis service = new Mobil.webService.KartServis()
        {
            Url = Application.Current.Properties["servisyolu"].ToString()
        };
        List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler> MusteriLists = new List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler>(service.MusteriListele(mCkp, bas, bit, mKodu, mFirma, mSehir, mSemt, mIlce, mAdres, Application.Current.Properties["lisans"].ToString(), Application.Current.Properties["KNO"].ToString()));
        if (MusteriLists.Count > 0)
        {
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                Show();
                foreach (Mobil.webService.Musteriler items in MusteriLists)
                {
                    Items.Add(new Musteriler { Kodu = items.Kodu, Firma = items.Firma, Adres = items.Adres, Telefon = items.Telefon, Sayi = items.Sayi });
                }
                listView.ItemsSource = Items;
                listView.ScrollTo(Items[bas], ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
                isLoading = false;
                Hide();
                return false;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            isLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to Load More Items at End of ListView in Xamarin.Forms ? Maybe you have something wrong with `listView.ItemsSource` .

Comment: depending on the earliest version of android you're targeting you should have a look at RecyclerView for implementing lists

Comment: Hi , have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the second 50 customers are listed, the scroll remains at the top of the list and remains in different positions.

**Reason one**: The next last item not exit.From bellow code,you should be sure `Items` have 100 datas after running bellow code.

```
foreach (Mobil.webService.Customer items in CustomerList)
    {
        Items.Add(new Customer { Kodu = items.code, City = items.City });
    }
```

**Reason two**: When running up code , need more time to finish it, you should add a timer or async task to finish it.Then continue the rest steps .

*Solution sample*: Test adding local datas to Items , and add timer to finish it.

```
private async Task LoadItems()
{
    isLoading = true;
    Title = "Loading";

    //simulator delayed load
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(string.Format("Item {0}", Items.Count));
        }
        Title = "Done";
        isLoading = false;
        listview.ScrollTo(Items[Items.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
        //stop timer
        return false;
    });
}
```

--------------------------------------------------------------Update------------------------------------------------------------

**Solution:** From sharing method **LoadItems** , the problems is bellow code；

```
listView.ScrollTo(listView.SelectedItem, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);
```

**You should remove up code**, because the trigger of the `LoadItems` method that causes the infinite loop is loaded with +100 each time in your code, and the program interface will soon be stuck.

```
    public async void LoadItems()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        Show();

        listView.ItemsSource = null;
        bas = bas + 50;
        bit = bit + 50;


          Mobil.webService.KartServis service = new Mobil.webService.KartServis()
          {
             Url = Application.Current.Properties["servisyolu"].ToString()
          };
          List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler> MusteriLists = new List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler>(service.MusteriListele("K", bas, bit, mKodu, mFirma, mSehir, mSemt, mIlce, mAdres, Application.Current.Properties["lisans"].ToString(), Application.Current.Properties["KNO"].ToString()));
          foreach (Mobil.webService.Musteriler items in MusteriLists)
          {
              Items.Add(new Musteriler { Kodu = items.Kodu, Firma = items.Firma,   Adres = items.Adres, Telefon = items.Telefon, Sayi = items.Sayi });
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(Items[i].Sayi);
          }
          var lastItem = Items[1];
          listView.ItemsSource = Items;
          isLoading = false;

          listView.SelectedItem = lastItem;
          //listView.ScrollTo(listView.SelectedItem, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);
          Hide();

    }
```

If not removing , you should add a Timer to check whether it is loop adding items.This bellow code will loop add items ,this may not a good logic.

```
public async void LoadItems()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        Show();

        listView.ItemsSource = null;
        bas = bas + 50;
        bit = bit + 50;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () =>
        {
          Mobil.webService.KartServis service = new Mobil.webService.KartServis()
          {
             Url = Application.Current.Properties["servisyolu"].ToString()
          };
          List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler> MusteriLists = new List<Mobil.webService.Musteriler>(service.MusteriListele("K", bas, bit, mKodu, mFirma, mSehir, mSemt, mIlce, mAdres, Application.Current.Properties["lisans"].ToString(), Application.Current.Properties["KNO"].ToString()));
          foreach (Mobil.webService.Musteriler items in MusteriLists)
          {
              Items.Add(new Musteriler { Kodu = items.Kodu, Firma = items.Firma,   Adres = items.Adres, Telefon = items.Telefon, Sayi = items.Sayi });
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(Items[i].Sayi);
          }
          var lastItem = Items[1];
          listView.ItemsSource = Items;
          isLoading = false;

          listView.SelectedItem = lastItem;
          listView.ScrollTo(listView.SelectedItem, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);
          Hide();
        });
    }
```

Note: If this Api getting 50 items every time, there is no other problems.

> List MusteriLists = new List(service.MusteriListele("K", bas, bit, mKodu, mFirma, mSehir, mSemt, mIlce, mAdres, Application.Current.Properties["lisans"].ToString(), Application.Current.Properties["KNO"].ToString()));

If not every time getting 50 , you should set `Items = new List<Musteriler>();` in **LoadItems**.Then Itmes.count will be 50,100,150,etc.Otherwise it will be 50,150,300,etc.This will produce an unexpected number of items.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've shared the entire code. I'll be glad, if you help me.

Comment: @Mesutönal Thanks for replying.I will update answer.

Comment: can you write the entire code? I'm updating my code the last time. The code doesn't work the way I want. Not working on Android side. I think because of the timer.

Comment: getting customer list through web service. I'll load the top 50 customers when the page loads. I then want to load the second 50 customers when I scroll down the page. I'd appreciate it if you had another method and you could help. I couldn't do it.

Comment: @Mesutönal Yeah ,I have given the entire code.I will update again with more explains.Because can not getting your api data, so something will not be tested in my local project.I have seen your updated answer with LoadItems .Do this work ?

Comment: i have a soap service. bas = first item (1), bit second item (50). inside loaditem bas and bit ++50

Comment: @Mesutönal Okey , if project shared , this can be tested.However from answer your problem can be solved by yourself .If be helpful , mark it when you have time :)